# In postfix, how to deny a specific email address from sending e-mail but still allow receiving?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

The closest thing I tried was to add `reject_unlisted_sender` to main.conf but that also disables receiving any email to that mailbox. I want only deny sending but still allow receiving.

**EDIT**

Here's [output of postfinger](https://clbin.com/BVOll).

If that really isn't what you want @UsersUser, here's [output of requested commands](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ychaouche/90819d368967d245af89/raw/30807011fcd207f33ab43483b0f341e09a70169b/gistfile1.txt)

Comment: `check_sender_access` and `man 5 access`?

Comment: Please give us more details. How will be sender connect to your postfix? Do you want to disable external or internal sending? We need also output from `postconf -n` and `postconf -mF`

Comment: Feel free to add your solution in answer section below....

Comment: It is your solution @masegaloeh, it would only make sense you post that as an answer and I'd validate it.

Comment: I'm too *lazy* to write answer right now :) That's why I only give you an idea and lets you explore it.... :p

Comment: @UsersUser  "How will be sender connect to your postfix" : just deny sending from any connection. "Do you want to disable external or internal sending?" : any sending. "We need also output from postconf -n and postconf -mF" question updated to include links to configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @masegaloeh suggested, here's what I did :

## In main.cf

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf
```

This tells postfix to perform the `check_sender_access` restriction on every sender before mail is sent. `mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf` contains the necessary SQL query to perform the check. If the result of the query is `"REJECT"` then postfix will deny sending the mail from that sender. So what we want is to create a database, add an access table, and for every sender we want to ban we'll insert a line with a "REJECT" value. To lift the ban, we update that value to "PERMIT". The other possible value is "DEFER". (see [postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html))

I am administering a server that was apparently configured using ISPConfig, so I already found a database, table and configuration file ready. I just inserted a new row.

## In /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf

```
root@messagerie-test[10.10.10.26]/home/serveur # cat /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf
user = ispconfig
password = xxx
dbname = dbispconfig
table        = mail_access
select_field = access
where_field  = source
additional_conditions = and type = 'sender' and active = 'y' and server_id = 1
hosts = 127.0.0.1
root@messagerie-test[10.10.10.26]/home/serveur #
```

This gives postfix the necessary information to perform the query. The database is `dbispconfig`, the table to query is `mail_access`, and the field to query, the one that will be holding the `"REJECT"` value is `"access".` Postfix will provide the sender's email and it will be matched against the `"source"` field (the `WHERE` clause).

## In the `dbispconfig.mail_access` table, here's what I have added

```
mysql> INSERT INTO mail_access (sys_userid,sys_groupid,sys_perm_user,sys_perm_group,server_id,source,access,type,active) VALUES (1,2,'ruid','ruid',1,'chaine2@algerian-radio.dz','REJECT','sender','y');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> select * from mail_access;
+-----------+------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| access_id | sys_userid | sys_groupid | sys_perm_user | sys_perm_group | sys_perm_other | server_id | source                    | access | type   | active |
+-----------+------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
|         1 |          1 |           2 | ruid          | ruid           |                |         1 | chaine2@algerian-radio.dz | REJECT | sender | y      |
+-----------+------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

The values for the other fields (other than access) were borrowed from other tables, they are specific to ISPConfig and have nothing to do with postfix. The important fields here are really source, access, type and active. These fields are in the `/etc/posftix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf` configuration file that we instructed postfix to use with `check_sender_access`.

Comment: Couldn't do it on the same day, thanks for the reminder :) !